# ¿Me podrían ayudar a diferenciar que es un endpoint y una API?

Tags: nodejs, api, backend, endpoint

Estoy algo confundido en entender exactamente cual es la diferencia entre un endpoint y una API, estoy desarrollando en node JS pero estos terminos me confunden un poco.

Comment: No creo que esté basada en opiniones. Sí puede ser que sea un concepto abstracto, pero hay una relación inteligible. Si fuera basada en opiniones dos máquinas que por naturaleza dependen de un resultado determinístico, no podrían interactuar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una vez respondí a [la diferencia entre un endpoint y un entrypoint](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51758/qu%C3%A9-es-un-entry-point-y-un-end-point/51764)

Complementando, el API es todo lo que expones como "superficie de contacto" para que una aplicación hable con la tuya sin intervención humana (esto es: no va a usar un browser y no necesita estilos, tipografías, etc, sólo información bruta que se lee, crea, actualiza o elimina).

API significa Application Programming Interface, en donde interfaz alude directamente al contrato de interfaz. Tu implementación es una caja negra. Los demás sólo saben que en tales endpoints y con tales payloads se hace tal o cual cosa.

Puedes cambiar lo que quieras en la caja negra y el API no ha cambiado, por tanto el API

- no es el backend,
- no es la capa de negocios,
- no es el webserver.

Es un contrato, en el fondo.

## Diferencia entre API y endpoint

un API puede tener muchos endpoints. Lo importante es que sin importar lo que tengas en tu capa de persistencia, negocios, webservers, etc, el que consume tu API sólo necesita saber cómo intercambiar información con ésta estableciendo:

- Cómo expresar QUIÉN está interactuando (autenticación)
- QUÉ puede hacer (endpoint)

  - QUÉ acción (leer, actualizar, crear, borrar y más)
  - DÓNDE se hace eso (ruta, usualmente contiene un espacio de nombre que sugiere sobre qué entidad se está operando e.g. `User`, `Post` o `Comment`)
  - QUÉ se espera que envíe (payload)
- QUÉ cabe recibir recibir de vuelta (respuesta)

  - CÓMO debe interpretar ciertos códigos en la respuesta (headers y error codes) para actuar en consecuencia
  - QUÉ forma tiene lo que el API responderá en el body para automatizar su procesamiento

## Variaciones

No hay tal cosa como una norma que defina cómo debe ser un API (y por eso hay aberraciones de grandes empresas donde parece que distintos equipos que se odiaban entre sí hicieron los distintos namespaces) así que hay muchos aspectos que quedan a criterio del ingeniero de software a la hora de definir la forma y comportamiento de un endpoint:

- Espacios de nombre en singular o plural (eg `User` vs `Users`)
- Schema de las respuestas. Por ejemplo al borrar un Post el API puede responderte

  - con un header 200 y la estructura del Post que acabas de borrar.
  - con un header 204 y nada en el body
- Anidación del schema: si pides la información de un Post puede devolverte

  - exactamente el schema de un post
  - un objeto que tiene una llave data que tiene una llave result que tiene un arreglo de posts con un solo elemento que tiene el schema de un post (gracias Facebook :facepalm)

Así con muchas otras cosas que no están escritas en fuego.

---

## Service Pack

Lo siguiente puede tener interpretaciones que obedecen a mi entendimiento (no opinión) y no soy sacerdote de APIs como para hacer exégesis pero me gano la vida en esto y si tuviera que explicarlo, usaría un ejemplo. Un eCommerce muy básico.

El ecommerce más básico expondría un API que tiene:

(Internamente) Tres **entidades**: usuario, pedido y productos

- pedido expone dos **rutas**

  - api.dominio.com/pedido
  - api.dominio.com/pedido/:idPedido
- pero en realidad expone cuatro **endpoints**

  - GET api.dominio.com/pedido (lista los pedidos)
  - POST api.dominio.com/pedido (crea un pedido)
  - PUT api.dominio.com/pedido/:idPedido (actualiza un pedido)
  - DELETE api.dominio.com/pedido/:idPedido (borra un pedido)
  - GET api.dominio.com/pedido/:idPedido (muestra detalle de un pedido)

Tus entidades son conceptuales. **NO SON PARTE DE TU API**. Dentro de la caja negra pueden ser modelos, tablas de excel, objetos JSON, pulpos pegajosos o la espada de He-Man.

Es bueno que los endpoints reflejen cierta lógica conceptual, pero al que consuma tu API no le importa cómo lo manejas por dentro.

---

Las otras entidades replican algo parecido, PERO, el usuario no puede modificar a otros ni modificar el catálogo. Esto implica que *los endpoints de tus entidades* requieren distintos **permisos**

Sin embargo esos permisos **NO SON PARTE DE TU API** sino de tu implementación. Por ejemplo:

- Un admin sí debiera poder modificar el catálogo y quizá a los clientes, por tanto tus usuarios tienen distintos **Roles**. Por ejemplo: "todos", "autenticados" y "admin". (todos contiene a autenticados y autenticados contiene a admin).
- Las NxM combinaciones de roles con permisos definen para cada entidad un **ACL** (Access Control Level)

**Sin embargo**, tu API no tiene por qué exponer los ACL ni los roles. Eso va dentro de tu caja negra. El que consume tu API sólo conoce los endpoints que sean visibles. **Por lo tanto los endpoints tienen visibilidad** que tú determinas. Esa visibilidad puede ser pública (e.g. el endpoint para registrarse) o requerir **autenticación** (por ejemplo ver el perfil).

Esta autenticación la manejarías con un flujo (que **Sí** es parte del api) que concluye entregándole al usuario **algo** para que en sus siguientes peticiones puedas saber quién es. Internamente (**NO** es parte del API) ese algo se mapea a un usuario y sus permisos. Pero eso es dentro de la caja negra.

Idealmente (a menos que el masoquismo supere todo límite) la autenticación será homogénea en toda tu API. En algún momento elegirás un mecanismo (Oauth, JWT, Simple Auth, *Sesiones, Cookies*. No, es broma, ni sesiones ni cookies, mala idea) y lo establecerás en tu contrato de interfaz. **Sí** es parte del API.

---

Como el usuario tiene pedidos y el pedido tiene productos, es intuitivo que en realidad tus endpoint sean (por ejemplo) de la forma:

- `POST api.dominio.com/user/:idUser/pedidos/:idPedido/producto` (añadir producto al pedido). Por tanto tus entidades tienen **relaciones**

(**no** son parte de tu API pero los endpoints permite inferirlas)

Como podría ser un poco rebuscado que para modificar la cantidad de cierto producto en un cierto pedido tuvieras que hacer `PUT api.dominio.com/user/:idUser/pedidos/:idPedido/producto/:idProducto` 
 en tu interfaz (por tanto SÍ es parte del API) indicas que eso se hace directo en `PUT api.dominio.com/pedidos/:idPedido/producto/:idProducto`.

Significa que los endpoints, como dijimos antes, tienen una cierta visibilidad (parte del API) que no se desprende directo de las entidades y sus métodos (que son internos) sino que además los puedes hacer invisibles por simplicidad, redundancia y sanidad mental.

---

Tu API espera que para añadir un producto al pedido le manden  el id en el cuerpo de la petición, mientras que eliminarlo requiere enviar el id en la URL. De la misma manera hacer login requiere mandar usuario y contraseña en el body. Significa que dependiendo de la acción tu API espera distintos **payloads**. Y eso sí es parte del API. La manera en que el API decodifica el contenido de la petición también debiera ser parte del contrato de interfaz.

Dependiendo del resultado de tu operación, el API entregará una **respuesta**:

- En los headers de la respuesta (en particular en el status code)

  - 404 si se intenta operar sobre una entidad que no existe
  - 401 si hay problema de permiso (por ACL o autenticación)
  - 200 si todo salió bien
  - 204 si se borró exitosamente la entidad (en realidad se usa poco)
- En el cuerpo de la respuesta

  - un objeto con la forma de un producto (nombre, precio, categoría) cuando pides el detalle de éste
  - un objeto usuario (email, nombre, userId, avatar) cuando pides tu perfil
  - un objeto authorization (token, userId) cuando te logueas
  - Un objeto error (código, mensaje, stack) cuando ocurre un error

Tus respuestas sí son parte de tu API, y pueden venir en distinto formato. Parte del contrato de interfaz de explicitar que tu respuesta es por ejemplo Json o XML. (Header  Content-Type)

Comment: Era demasiada información y como recibí un voto en contra me cuestioné si estaba haciendo más mal que bien